# can django running on apache with mod_wsgi cause any memory leaks?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

The current configuration I have has been running perfectly for more than one year.

My apache is configured to include this mod_wsgi configuration:

```
    Alias /uploads/ "/home/django/myproject/uploads/"
<Directory "/home/django/myproject/uploads/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all 
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "/home/django/myproject/sitestatic/"
<Directory  "/home/django/myproject/sitestatic/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all 
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/django/myproject/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/django/myproject/apache">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

And my /home/django/myproject/apache/django.wsgi looks like this:

```
import os
import sys 

sys.path.append('/home/django')
sys.path.append('/home/django/myproject')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='myproject.settings'

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Pretty typical I guess.

In my httpd.conf I have this line:

```
    Include "/home/django/myproject/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

Whenever this conf is loaded, apache processes jump at 100% causing me MemoryErrors ...

When I comment out the include line above, starting apache is smooth and as it should, memory wise.

I couldnt find anything in the apache logs, even set it on debug mode.

It is obvious this memory leak, if I may call it so, it is cause by either mod_wsgi or my django app.

How would you recommend to trace the error/isolate the issue? Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a buggy function in one of my django apps which was holding everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the resources used by mod_wsgi in your apache configuration. Try this

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess yourname.com processes=1 threads=2 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup yourname.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/myproject/apache/django.wsgi
```

you can set the number of processes and threads etc. Check the options here http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt help. If processes is set to 1 then all memory goes to that process. Any other ideas?